# Script not accessing Files and Folders in a shared Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am listed as a manager on a shared drive in our organisation.  I can view, open and edit the files and folders in Google Drive using the browser.  The folder I am interested in contains 2 folders and a number of various filetypes.

I am using Apps Script in Google Sheets to get a list of files and folders that meet certain conditions.  When I tried to get a list of the files and folders from my target folder using Google Drive API (V2), the script could see 0 files and 0 folders.  When I used the built-in DriveApp service, it timed out for what I was trying to achieve; so thought Google Drive API should hopefully be quicker.  I can confirm that DriveApp could see the folder titles - I used that for testing in the Logger log.

This test code is supposed to return the number of folders in a given folder (and confirm the account used).  Can anyone advise why I am getting the number of folders return as 0 even though I have organizer-level permissions, the Drive Service active and the correct Folder ID ?  There are definitely 2 folders in my test target that I have permissions for and am not getting any error messages.

```
function countFolderFolders() {
// Create a Drive API client
  var folderId = 'ABCD123';  // AMEND to suit
  var driveApi;
  try {
    driveApi = Drive.Files.list({
    q: "'" + folderId + "' in parents and trashed = false and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'", // Query - count folders in the specified folder
    maxResults: 1000
    });
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Drive API Error: ' + e.toString());
    return;
  }

  if (driveApi && driveApi.items) {
  // Count the number of folders
    var folderCount = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < driveApi.items.length; i++) {
      var item = driveApi.items[i];
      if (item.mimeType === "application/vnd.google-apps.folder") {
        folderCount++;
      }
    }

    Logger.log('The number of folders in the folder with the ID "' + folderId + '" is: ' + folderCount);
  } else {
    Logger.log('No folders found or error occurred.');
  }
  testAccount();
}


function testAccount() {
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log('The script is being run under the account: ' + email);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
driveApi = Drive.Files.list({
q: "'" + folderId + "' in parents and trashed = false and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'", // Query - count folders in the specified folder
maxResults: 1000
});
```

#### To:

```
driveApi = Drive.Files.list({
  q: "'" + folderId + "' in parents and trashed = false and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'", // Query - count folders in the specified folder
  maxResults: 1000,
  corpora: "allDrives",
  includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
  supportsAllDrives: true
});
```

#### Note:

- In this case, it supposes that you have permission to read the files and folders from the shared drive. Please be careful about this.
- By the way, from your search query of `"'" + folderId + "' in parents and trashed = false and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"`, in this case, only the folders are retrieved. So, I thought that the following modification might be able to be used.

  - From

    ```js
    if (driveApi && driveApi.items) {
    // Count the number of folders
      var folderCount = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < driveApi.items.length; i++) {
        var item = driveApi.items[i];
        if (item.mimeType === "application/vnd.google-apps.folder") {
          folderCount++;
        }
      }

      Logger.log('The number of folders in the folder with the ID "' + folderId + '" is: ' + folderCount);
    } else {
      Logger.log('No folders found or error occurred.');
    }
    ```
  - To

    ```js
    if (driveApi && driveApi.items) {
    // Count the number of folders
      var folderCount = driveApi.items.length;

      Logger.log('The number of folders in the folder with the ID "' + folderId + '" is: ' + folderCount);
    } else {
      Logger.log('No folders found or error occurred.');
    }
    ```

#### Reference:

- [Method: files.list of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/files/list)

Comment: Thank you so much Tanaike.  I was going in circles with that.

Comment: @Glib Gibon Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.