# Google Sheet and Apps Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-drive-shared-drive

new here and looking for information and direction on how to use google sheets and the apps script function to pull shared drive data into a google sheet. I want to pull data like file name, modified date, created date, file link and etc into a google sheet. It will be a specific drive not the my drive. Is that possible?

Well i have been looking into some "get file" script in apps, but I can't seem to see how to change it from a my drive to a specific shared drive or folder.

Comment: If you can get the id of the folder your interested in you could use [DriveApp.getFolderById(id,resourceKey)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFolderByIdAndResourceKey(String,String)).  You may need a resource key.

Comment: What type of files are you looking for on the shared drives?

Comment: You may find it easier to access files in the shared drives with Drive  API which requires you to enable in the cloud console. You can find a link to it in the settings section of the script editor. This may also require you to change your project type

Comment: Related questions: [Script not accessing Files and Folders in a shared Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77226135/1330560), [Google Apps Script from My Drive to Shared Drives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71868255/1330560) and [Accessing shared drive with DriveApp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58171105/1330560).

Comment: Thank you for your assistance it seems as though when i tried to run the app script i got a message not allowed by my admin. So i think that I might try something different, I will see what permissions i have first.